# Extract WHERE clause from JPA/Hibernate Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How can I extract the `WHERE` clause from a JPA `javax.persistence.Query`, if possible at all? Possibly as a `Predicate`.

For example, given:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.total > 1000");
```

how can I extract the `o.total > 1000` from `query`? I'm using Hibernate 5.1.

Comment: `String where = "o.total > 1000"; String query = "SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE " + where;` So, `where` variable holds what you need.

Comment: Thank you @DraganBozanovic, unfortunately that was an example, but in practice I receive the `Query` object from an external source. I'll edit the question to make that clearer!

Comment: Ok, you should definitely add more details to the question. For example, which `where` do you want from here: `SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.total > 1000 and o.otherEntity in (SELECT oe FROM OtherEntity oe WHERE oe.total > 500)`?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of JPA. You have to look in to the specifics of your JPA provider ... for example the implementation I use (DataNucleus) I can do "query.toString()" to get the overall JPQL and from that parse out the WHERE clause, or I can delve deeper and grab the specific components by using DataNucleus classes